# Issues Converting wstring to TCHAR

Tags: c++, cstring, wstring, tchar

I'm fairly new to programming, and I'm trying to write a program where a user inputs a date, then that date is added to the file directory name, then that file directory is searched.

Here is what I'm working with below.  I have a number of functions to do this.. I've searched online and tried doing the conversion a few different ways and I'm just not understanding it.... so I left off with (what I know is incorrected)  a static_cast.

Maybe I'm just not doing the conversion right...  basically this will throw it back to a function that uses the WINAPI handler.  Whether I can get that to work is a completely different story...   Thanks in advance for any help!

```
wstring fDate;
wstring fileDin;

const TCHAR* s = _T (fileDin);

std::wstring(fDate);
std::wstring(fileDin) =L"Z:\\software\\A\\AC\\" + fDate;
wcout<< fileDin;
cout <<endl;

//wstring fileDin(&arc[1]);
fileDin = static_cast<TCHAR>(arc[1]);
dir(2, arc);
```

Comment: In your case it is better to avoid using `TCHAR`

Answer (score 1):

`TCHAR` can be either `wchar_t` (when you use Unicode) or `char` (when you use Multi-byte).
On the other hand `std::wstring` always contains characters of type `wchar_t`, so it's better if you use `wchar_t*` directly instead of `TCHAR*` (if possible).

Then `wchar_t*` to `std::wstring` conversion can be done by using constructor of `std::wstring`:

```
wchar_t* wcstr = L"my string";
std::wstring wstr(wcstr);
```

and `std::wstring` to `wchar_t*` by simple calling `c_str()` method:

```
wchar_t* wcstr = wstr.c_str();
```

Then sometimes you might need to convert between "wide" strings (`std::wstring`s holding `wchar_t` characaters) and multi-byte strings (`std::string`s holding `char`s). I usually use following helpers:

```
// multi byte to wide char:
std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& str)
{
    int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), NULL, 0);
    std::wstring wstrTo(size_needed, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &wstrTo[0], size_needed);
    return wstrTo;
}

// wide char to multi byte:
std::string ws2s(const std::wstring& wstr)
{
    int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wstr.c_str(), int(wstr.length() + 1), 0, 0, 0, 0); 
    std::string strTo(size_needed, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wstr.c_str(), int(wstr.length() + 1), &strTo[0], size_needed, 0, 0); 
    return strTo;
}
```

Comment: Based on the fact that `_T(fileDin)` compiled without error, the configuration must be set so that `TCHAR` is `char`. That means this answer won't work, unfortunately.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Good point. I still think that in most cases it is more straightforward and thus better to work with either `wchar_t*` or `char*` explicitly rather than using `TCHAR`.

Comment: Agreed, `TCHAR` is a relic of a time long past. Unfortunately many of us still work with code bases dating from those times and as a matter of consistency need to keep using it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the code that was given to me when utilizing FindFirstFile() or FindNextFile(), and it took me a good while to get the hang of that.  If there were an easier way to search and pull names of files I don't know from a directory , I'd probably be able to bypass that whole piece of the function.  I may try rewriting using wchar_t* if it will do what I need it to.